# How to handle clashing virtual environments in Python

Tags: python, virtual, environment

We have an application that uses Python 3.6.1 (and other things like Django, mod_wsgi, Rabbitmq). The manager for the app was originally built on Windows and I've been transferring it to Linux. To get everything running, I moved the app into a virtual environment. The problem I'm having now is that I'm trying to call the various third party apps that we've used before and one of them is set up in its own virtual environment (using Python 2.7). I can't get that app to run from within the new Python 3 environment. When I run the code that calls the 3rd party app, the import fails. I tried making changes to the file that refuses to import, to make syntax changes needed for Python 3 compatibility, but it still doesn't import and I'm concerned that I would have to do that for the entire application. And it still might not work or be the right way to go.

I understand that part of what the environment setup does is change environment variables and puts what it needs at the beginning of paths, so it makes sense to me that these two environments are in conflict. I don't know how to make it work. Is there any way to get two virtual environments to work together? And more specifically, is there a *good* way to get them to work together?

Comment: So the failed imports are in your code or third party code? (just for the record if they are in third party code do pip freeze in old environment then install them in the new one and you should be good to go). If they are in your own code, are these scripts used to be imported or called themselves?

Comment: The import statement is in our code. I thought about trying to put their code into our folders but haven't tried that yet. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: That said I think this is what you are looking for: http://python-future.org/translation.html (If I am not mistaken)

Answer (score -1):

The virtual environment tree contains a `bin` directory, and setuptools will install stub programs there that correctly set up the Python environment and then run some main function within that.  This means you can *directly* run one of those stub programs without "activating" the virtual environment or setting up any environment variables.

If you have a directory tree that looks roughly like:

```
\--.virtualenvs
  +-- app-py37
  | +-- bin
  | | \-- app
  | \-- lib
  |   \-- ...
  |     \-- app_main.py
  +-- other-py27
    +-- bin
    | \-- helper
    \-- lib
      \-- ...
        \-- helper_main.py
```

and you invoked the helper with a call like

```
import os
import subprocess
subprocess.run([os.path.join(os.environ('HOME'),
                             '.virtualenvs', 'other-py27', 'bin', 'helper'],
               check=True)
```

I would expect it to correctly set up its own Python environment.

Comment: So it would set up the py27 environment *inside* the py36 environment?

Comment: I don't think he is calling python whatever, I think he is importing modules from one app into the other, but one is built on 27 the other on 36 is that right?

Comment: The `subprocess.run()` call would launch a new Python (2.7) interpreter which would be pointing at the "other" virtual environment.  It wouldn't know anything about the calling process (for instance that it happened to be a Python 3.6 script in a different virtual environment).

Comment: @E.Serra You are correct, I am importing modules and calling methods, not launching something that is then running completely separately. And btw, "he" is "she" (dang my parents for giving me one of those boy-or-girl names.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't see anything in their bin folder that looks like what you are talking about, unfortunately.

Comment: Unconscious bias, just assumed a dev would be a man, my bad.
DavidMaze method does not work because it relies on a python script called from command line, check the other comment I made or google import from python2 to python3, or try the can_i_use_python3 thing, it will give you clues on what needs to change. Also IIRC module structure (__init__.py files and imports are slightly different).
A horrible quick hack would be to change the sys path to include the files in the other virtualenv, maybe that will do the trick but I would suggest making ALL your code python3 compatible

Comment: @E.Serra I'm looking into the link you made above. No luck so far but I need to read more. Thanks for your suggestions. And I've been dealing with that unconscious bias for 30 years. I try to take it with a grain of salt ;-)